# jQuery selector that simulates :starts-with or :ends-with for searching text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-selectors, contains

If you look at the [selectors list](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) on the jQuery website, there are selectors for starts-with and ends-with on attributes. There's also a `:contains` selector for searching text:

```
alert( $("div").find("span:contains(text)").html() );
```

Does jQuery have an implementation for searching strings using starts-with or ends-with?

FYI: I need to search through an XML object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not by default as far as I know, but you can add your own pseudo-selectors through `$.expr[":"]`: http://jsfiddle.net/h6KYk/.

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "starts-with": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),
            term = data[3];

        // first index is 0
        return text.indexOf(term) === 0;
    },

    "ends-with": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),
            term = data[3];

        // last index is last possible
        return text.lastIndexOf(term) === text.length - term.length;
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Thank you very much.  I appreciate your input.  Could you please elaborate on your process?  What is the purpose of "set" and "i" in each function?  And what is data[3]?  Thank you, again.

Comment: @user717236: The function you set in `$.expr[":"]` is passed several arguments so as to decide whether or not a certain element should pass. `elem` is the element to test, and `i` is a counter. `data` is an array which contains values of the selector; `data[3]` will be the string `"foo"` if you select using `:starts-with('foo')`. `set` is a set of all elements that is being filtered by your function, so e.g. `div:starts-with('foo')` will pass all `div`s as `set`, which are then filtered by the function.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, @pimvdb.  Is there a resource I can look up which provides more in-depth discussion on this topic?  For example, you specified four parameters in each function.  Are these variables at all related to jQuery's find method declaration (i.e. function(a) { var b=this, c, d; ... })?

Comment: @user717236: Not directly as far as I know. They are part of Sizzle, jQuery's selector engine. I cannot find an official article on this subject, but [this one](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html) seems to explain it a bit. As a side note, you seem to have posted a function of the minified version of jQuery. The readable code is at http://jquery.com/ as "development" version.

Answer (score 13):

When you don't want to extend jQuery, you can use the `filter()` function to create the contains functionality:

```
$("div").find("span").filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf(text) >= 0;
});
```

Or create a startsWith function with a regular expression:

```
var expression = new RegExp('^' + text);
$("div").find("span").filter(function () {
    return expression.test($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

The endsWith function is quite similar:

```
var expression = new RegExp(text + '$');
$("div").find("span").filter(function () {
    return expression.test($.trim($(this).text()));
});
```

Note the use of `$.trim()` because HTML can contain a lot of whitespace.