# Apply CSS style to span tag based on content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I don't know if this is possible, but I am trying to apply a style to a `span` tag based on its content.

I have some tags on a blog site that are stored in a `span` tag and would like to style them based on their content.

```js
$(“#col-cell.span:contains(‘c’)”).css(‘color’,’blue’);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-cell">
  <span>cloud</span>
  <span>business</span>
  <span>social</span>
</div>
```

I found this jQuery command, but didn't have much luck with it.

Comment: if the answer didnt work or you are still facing trouble with this issue let me know so I can help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Use `.` instead of `#` for `col-cell` since it is referring to a class
2. Use a **space** between `col-cell` and **span** to indicate you are searching for children
3. Within `:contains()` itself, do not use quotes

```js
$('.col-cell span:contains(c)').css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-cell">
  <span>cloud</span>
  <span>business</span>
  <span>social</span>
</div>
```

**Update**

> hi i have managed to get it to work now, thank you, there one other thing, i would like to use another selector instead of :contain, and use a selector based on the first character of the word

From [jQuery selector that simulates :starts-with or :ends-with for searching text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213907/jquery-selector-that-simulates-starts-with-or-ends-with-for-searching-text)

```js
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    "starts-with": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),
            term = data[3];

        // first index is 0
        return text.indexOf(term) === 0;
    },

    "ends-with": function(elem, i, data, set) {
        var text = $.trim($(elem).text()),
            term = data[3];

        // last index is last possible
        return text.lastIndexOf(term) === text.length - term.length;
    }
});
$('span:starts-with(c)').css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-cell">
  <span>cloud</span>
  <span>business</span>
  <span>social</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, makes perfect sense, however i dont seem to be able to get it to work  

I've even tried this

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.col-cell span a:contains(c)').css('background-color', 'blue');
      })

Comment: hi i have managed to get it to work now, thank you, there one other thing, i would like to use another selector instead of :contain, and use a selector based on the first character of the word