# How do I change the text color of a td to red

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the styles defined in my css file

I want to apply this style if the Text in my

```
<tr>
    <td class="lalign"><span class="ceoName"></span><span class="ceoTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoMondaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoTuesdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoWednesdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoThursdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoFridaySchedule"></span></td>                
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="lalign"><span class="cfoName"></span><span class="cfoTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;"></span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoMondaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoTuesdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoWednesdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoThursdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoFridaySchedule"></span></td>                
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="lalign"><span class="ctoName"></span><span class="ctoTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoMondaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoTuesdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoWednesdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoThursdaySchedule"></span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoFridaySchedule"></span></td>                
</tr>
```

says **No Schedule Set**

```
<style type="text/css">
td.mytdclass {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Otherwise I want to use this style

```
<style>
td.mytdclass {
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

I am using jQuery on the client side.

I could write

```
$('.ceoMondaySchedule').each(function(idx, obj) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    console.log(txt);
    if (txt === "No Schedule Set" + "No Schedule Set") {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
    }
});

$('.ceoTuesdaySchedule').each(function(idx, obj) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    console.log(txt);
    if (txt === "No Schedule Set" + "No Schedule Set") {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
    }
});

$('.ceoWednesdaySchedule').each(function(idx, obj) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    console.log(txt);
    if (txt === "No Schedule Set" + "No Schedule Set") {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
    }
});
```

and keep doing it for all 5 days then do the same for cfo then cto

but is there a better way of writing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply CSS style to span tag based on content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207051/apply-css-style-to-span-tag-based-on-content)

Comment: How do we know if a schedule was set?

Comment: You can't have two different styles for `td.mytdclass` in your CSS.

Comment: You should have different classes, e.g. `td.redtd` and `td.blacktd`. Then the jQuery code can change the class of the `<td>` depending on the content.

Comment: The schedule being set occurs after the document is ready. We perform a .onchange('trigger') when a different date is selected. The table is regenerated using jQuery. The data is coming from a JSON file

Comment: `txt === "No Schedule Set" + "No Schedule Set")` makes no sense. It should be `"No Schedule Set"` or the new silly way `"No Schedule Set No Schedule Set"`. When dealing with string **literals**  using a `+` operand is usually to concat with one or more string variables possibly a single defined string if on the right side of expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After reviewing OP's strangely familiar edit in code, I updated my equally familiar code in response to a follow up question:

> *"I could write,"*

***Strangely familiar code***

> *"and keep doing it for all 5 days then do the same for cfo then cto but is there a better way of writing this?"*

Yes, just change the selector. The update features an attribute special value selector and a tag selector, the former being very specific and the latter more general.

> - `$('[class$="Schedule"]')` Means: Any element that has a className **ending** with the string: "Schedule".
> - `$('td span')` Means: Any span that's a child of a td.

I also added two buttons to demonstrate the two selector's range.

---

Use

- `.each()` To go to each target (i.e. `.jobTitle`) and perform a function
- `.text()` To find what text is actually inside a target (i.e.`No Schedule Set`)
- `.css()` To change a target's style (i.e. `color` `red`)

**SNIPPET**

```js
function targetSchedule() {
  $('[class$="Schedule"]').each(function(idx, obj) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt === 'No Schedule Set') {
      $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(this).css('color', 'black');
    }
  });
}

function targetAllSpan() {
  $('td span').each(function(idx, obj) {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if (txt === 'No Schedule Set') {
      $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    } else {
      $(this).css('font-size', 'smaller');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick='targetSchedule()'>Any className ending with "Schedule" and has the text "No Schedule Set" will have red text; anything else will have black text</button>
<button onclick='targetAllSpan()'>Any span that's a child of a td and has the text "No Schedule Set" will be underlined; anything else will have smaller text</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="lalign"><span class="ceoName">No Schedule Set</span><span class="ceoTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;">Schedule Set</span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoMondaySchedule">No Schedule Done</span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoTuesdaySchedule">Set Schedule No</span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoWednesdaySchedule">NoScheduleSet</span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoThursdaySchedule">No Schedule Set</span></td>
    <td><span class="ceoFridaySchedule">No Scedule Set</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="lalign"><span class="cfoName">No Schedule Set No</span><span class="cfoTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;">Schedule Set</span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoMondaySchedule">no schedule set</span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoTuesdaySchedule">No Schedule Set</span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoWednesdaySchedule">No</span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoThursdaySchedule">Schedule</span></td>
    <td><span class="cfoFridaySchedule">Set</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="lalign">Nope<span class="ctoName"></span><span class="ctoTitle" style="color: navy;text-align: center;">Set No Schedule</span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoMondaySchedule">没有设定时间表</span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoTuesdaySchedule">✦</span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoWednesdaySchedule">No Schedule Set</span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoThursdaySchedule">No Schedule Set</span></td>
    <td><span class="ctoFridaySchedule"></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the JQuery :contains() selector. This will select all elements that "contain" the specified string.

```
$( "td span.jobTitle:contains('No Schedule Set')" ).css({
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: "white"
})
```

Comment: I did something similar but when I change the input value and the data changes, the css that was applied when the schedule was not set is never removed.