# Wildcard/Logic syntax for the :contains selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use the :contains selector to more efficiently grab some elements. However, I'm not sure on the syntax for:

```
:contains(X AND Y)
:contains(X(any number of characters)Y)
```

X/Y are variables.

I could not find anything searching online that specifics using the :contains selector. All I found were fancy class selectors like ~=word and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no wildcard or logic applicable to `:contains` selector. It just matches the string inside it, but you can get by with these approaches.

For `:contains(X AND Y)` you can can combine two consecutive :contains selectors `:contains(X):contains(Y)`, which matches 'X' and 'Y' strings.

For `:contains(X(any number of characters)Y)` there is a question already answered that extends jQuery to add `:starts-with()` and `:ends-with()`. Combining both of them `:starts-with(X):ends-with(Y)` you get results that contains 'X(any number of characters)Y'.

[jQuery selector that simulates :starts-with or :ends-with for searching text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213907/jquery-selector-that-simulates-starts-with-or-ends-with-for-searching-text)